# Can I save the download link for the query string under a different name?

Tags: c#, string, browser

Let's say I have 100 connections:

video.mp4? 1234
video.mp4? 1221
....

When I want to download these links, it comes down to video.mp4.

Can I change it like this?

When I want to download it, it should automatically save with this name:

1234-video.mp4
1221-video.mp4

Is it possible to do this with any programming language?

If I encode a special browser, can I do something like this with c #?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to do this with any programming language?

Yes.

> can I do something like this with c #?

Yes.

When using IIS 7.0+ and with an Application Pool configured for Integrated Mode, you can handle all the requests (static file requests besides dynamic files like aspx, add, svc, etc..)

You can also do this during development using IISExpress (which is the default web server used by VS 2017 for web projects)

Let's assume that you have a web application with an assembly name `WebApplication1`

In your web.config file, set the following attribute (`runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests`) to true and add a new HTTP module definition as follows:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <add name="VideoDownloadHandler" type="WebApplication1.VideoDownloadHandler"/>
    </modules> 
</system.webServer>
```

Then implement `VideoDownloadHandler.cs` as a class in your web project as follows: (This code assumes that you have the video file video.mp4 under the /vid folder)

```
using System;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class VideoDownloadHandler : IHttpModule
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
            // Nothing to dispose
        }

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.BeginRequest += context_BeginRequest;
        }

        void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpRequest request = (sender as HttpApplication).Request;
            HttpResponse response = (sender as HttpApplication).Response;
            HttpApplication application = sender as HttpApplication;

            if (!request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToLowerInvariant().EndsWith("video.mp4"))
            {
                return;
            }

            string queryString = request.QueryString.ToString();
            string videoFileName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryString) ? "video.mp4" : queryString + "-video.mp4";

            response.ContentType = "video/mp4";
            response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + videoFileName + ";");
            response.TransmitFile("~/vid/video.mp4");
            response.Flush();
            application.CompleteRequest();
        }
    }
}
```

When your application receives a request for video.mp4, it is handled by your HttpModule, but all other requests are left alone for further processing.

As you can see, you can give the downloaded file any name (and here we are giving it the name `queryString + "-video.mp4"`

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort and answer.

Comment: Tekrardan çok sağol :)

Comment: You're welcome. I would be glad if you also can upvote. Rica ederim.

Comment: I can't send because my score is insufficient :/

 'Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. '